# Statistic of Sharepoint Pages

Tags: sharepoint-designer, statistics, sitepages

I want to get statistic in my Sharepoint Site. How often entered site pages? What popular page in sitepages. How can I do this? Is there any statistic function in Sharepoint Designer 2013 or another Statistic programe?

Thanks for advice.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout following custom solutions:

[Free Sharepoint Page Hits Web Part](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5844)

[Sharepoint - Hit Counter Webpart](http://hitcounter.codeplex.com/)

The later one can be further extended to show popular pages as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint out of the box feature "Popularity and Search Reports". You can found this link Site Collection settings of site.

Within Popularity and Search reports, you can export usage and queries report into excel to diagnose it.

Or you can use Google analytic too, embed it in master page for proper details of everything.

Popularity trend will not give you exactly that you are looking for. It will only give a a statistics that how many unique user visited to a specific site or item.
For more info how to use this feature read this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715890(v=office.15).aspx

Otherwise for more detailed, you need to use Google analytic on masterpage!

Comment: Hi @ateet I tried "Popularity and Search Reports". But it doesn't understandable. How can I get statistic of page's visit with this report.

Comment: @Zengel It doesn't give you exactly that you needed. It will only show you how many user visited to an item or site to a specific date. See my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

We generally embed Google Analytics in the main master page. It's very easy to do with SharePoint Designer. Make a copy/backup of the orginal master page in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Hi @W0ut thanks for advice. I tried get a new tracking Id for Google Analytics. When I write my sharepoint site's name, I'm getting this warning "URL ends with an invalid top-level name." But it is my site's homepage name. What i can write instead it's.